# textwidth=0 and wrapwidth=0 in .vimrc.local not being respected

Tags: vim, text-editors, macvim

I have the following lines at the bottom of my .vimrc.local:

```
set textwidth=0 
set wrapmargin=0
```

However, whenever I open a new file, both these values are set to their defaults (72 and 2, respectively) and not my custom settings. The other settings in my .vimrc.local file appear to be set (tabs, etc) but just these two keep being reset. If I enter `:source ~/.vimrc.local` the settings change and work correctly.

Is there a way to look at what is setting anything when vim starts up? I suspect that some plugin or setting that came with MacVim or Janus is setting these options, but I don't know how to look at every setting at once.

Comment: I had never seen `~/.vimrc.local` before. The [version of Janus that I found](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) sources it (if it exists) at the end of its `vimrc` file (which is the destination of the `~/.vimrc` symlink that it installs, if you use its installation method). Maybe not all versions of Janus do this—many people seem to merge the one I found into their forks, but I have no idea if this is the “official” one or not. Just to clarify, where did you get your Janus? If it is a Git-based one, which commit are you using?

Comment: Worth reading this [defaul formatoptions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/how-can-i-get-vim-to-stop-putting-comments-in-front-of-new-lines)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To find out where 'textwidth' and 'wrapmargin' were set last, execute

```
:verbose set tw? wm?
```

To see what files have been sourced, execute

```
:scriptnames
```

If those aren't enough to find the problem, you can use the -V option when Vim starts and log the various startup events to a file. See

```
:help -V
```

Also, the default values for 'textwidth' and 'wrapmargin' are both 0, not 72 and 2, so already something is setting them to non-default values. For the default values, see

```
:help 'textwidth'
:help 'wrapmargin'
```

**P.S.**
Something else to check is the possibility that a filetype plugin is making those settings. The `:verbose set ...` command should show where those settings are being made, but you could also execute

```
:set filetype?
```

to see the current filetype, then open `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`, where <filetype> is the value of the 'filetype' option found above, to see if those settings are being made there. You can override settings made by a filetype plugin by putting your settings in a file you create, named ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim. See

```
:help filetype-overrule
```

item #3.

Comment: Turns out the issue was in `~/.vimrc`, which came from Janus. I expected the `source ~/.vimrc.local` to be the last thing that executed, but it was setting those two with the `au` command. It seems like the settings in `~/.vimrc` contain a lot of stylistic choices of the people who maintain Janus. Thank you for writing an answer that will help me troubleshoot these problems for myself in the future. :)

Comment: I also came here due to this issue in Janus. But note, in the latest Janus `~/.vimrc.after` does get run last, however there was, for example, a python specific action happening, so I had to use `au FileType python set softtabstop=4 tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 textwidth=0` rather than simply `set textwidth=0` in that file.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this by adding the following to my **.vimrc.local** file:

```
" Disable annoying auto line break
fu! DisableBr()
    set wrap
    set linebreak
    set nolist  " list disables linebreak
    set textwidth=0
    set wrapmargin=0
    set fo-=t
endfu

" Disable line breaks for all file types
:au BufNewFile,BufRead *.* call DisableBr()
```

This should disable unwanted auto line breaks for all file types

Comment: Works in .vimrc.after when using Janus

Comment: Huzzah, thanks! This was the only thing that worked for me. For some reason (I couldn't work out) macvim was overriding the textwidth in my vimrc for .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

## This should help:

(Maybe `BufAdd` and `BufCreate` is redundant, but I added it just in case)

```
function! DisableWrap()
    set nowrap
    set nolinebreak
    set formatoptions-=cro
endfunction
autocmd BufNew,BufAdd,BufCreate,VimEnter * call DisableWrap()
```